# How to get to Google Play "Multi-Player Games" section with my game?

Tags: google-play-services, google-play-games, multiplayer, starling-framework, smartfoxserver

I have a multiplayer game distributed through Facebook, AppStore, and Google Play. I want my game to be listed in the "Multi-Player Games" section of the Google Play market.

[image: Google play multiplayer listing]

How should I do this?

Is it enough to add related Google Play Game Service (multiplayer) and my app will appear in the multiplayer section of Google Play?

[image: Google web services adjustment]

And also, we do not apply the Google API for implementing our game's multiplayer features, instead we use SmartFox Server. Is it acceptable, or does Google only list games built on its own multiplayer platform in the Google Play multiplayer section?

Answer (score 2):

To enable multiplayer support:

Open the Games with Game Services page from the Google Play Developer Console, and select your game.

Open the Linked apps page for your game, then switch the multiplayer setting to ON.

Click Save as draft to store your settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish an app which can be shown in the multiplayer games category even without using google play game service. Just make sure that you chose the correct options in the google play console when [publishing your app](http://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html).

Here are the specific options that you need to set under [content ratings](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/188189?hl=en):

- you must select the Games category.
- To make it multiplayer, you must answer one of the questionnaire that asks whether users can interact with other user to yes.

The game services tab setup is not required. You only need to set it up if you use the Google Play Games Services to build your game.

Comment: Thanks, for response. I regenerated the questionnaire for Content Ratings, indicated that users can interact with each others, and pushed an update to store.